# If matrices describe simplices, what do matrix operations describe?

Tags: matrices

Suppose we are given a $d \times d$ matrix $M$ with rows $m_1, \dots, m_d$.

This matrix describes a simplex, namely the convex closure of the origin with the vectors $m_1, \dots, m_d$.

Now, scaling the matrix by a scalar $s$ means scaling the simplex by the scalar $s$. And, say, multiplication from the right by a matrix means transforming that simplex.

Going further, you can view matrix operations as operations on simplices (with an ordering of their vertices and one vertex at the origin). Can you describe matrix operations in geometric terms, as operations on simplices? For example, what is the product of two simplices? What about the transpose, what about the inverse?